# Prevent makefile from recompiling the source files

Tags: javascript, makefile, stylus

Here's my makefile:

```
STYLES = $(wildcard views/*/*.styl)
CSS = $(STYLES:.styl=.css)

all: $(CSS)
    component build

%.css: %.styl
    @echo $<
```

This example will compile each time because the CSS files don't/will never exist because I'm building into `/build`. How can I build into another directory and not recompile the source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it, would love some suggestions on cleanup...

```
STYLUS = node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus
STYLES = $(subst views, , $(wildcard views/*/*.styl))
CSS = $(STYLES:.styl=.css)

all: $(addprefix build, $(CSS))
    component build

build/%.css: views/%.styl
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(STYLUS) -u nib -o $(dir $@) $<

clean:
    rm -rf build

.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score -1):

I know your question pertains specifically to a makefile, however you might consider using grunt.js (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-stylus/) for building your stylus projects. It's javascript based and runs on node.js, and it's far easier to setup, configure and maintain than using make.

Plus you can use grunt to easily manage the build process for your entire project, so if you need to concatenate and minify your javascripts, and then clean out temp folders after the build, just add those tasks... it's a pretty awesome build system.